# Does the validation of an ICAO licence allow you to fly internationally?

Tags: pilot-certification, icao, ppl

Hypothetical situation:

A pilot with an ICAO-compliant PPL licence from Australia goes to France and France issues a licence validation in accordance with the Chicago Convention, thus allowing him to fly aircraft registered in France.

If this pilot wants to take a French-registered aircraft to another country is this possible? From Article 33 of the chicago convention it seems like this should be allowed, but is it actually in practice?

> **Article 33**
> *Recognition of certificates and licenses*
>
> Certificates of airworthiness and certificates of competency
> and licenses issued **or rendered valid** by the contracting State
> in which the aircraft is registered, **shall be recognized as valid
> by the other contracting States**, provided that the requirements
> under which such certificates or licences were issued or
> rendered valid are equal to or above the minimum standards
> which may be established from time to time pursuant to this
> Convention.

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12220/62)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing the validation e.g. in France you will get a validation from an EASA member which enables you to fly an EASA registered plane world-wide.

EASA includes registered planes from

```
Austria
Belgium
Bulgaria
Croatia
Cyprus
Czech Republic
Denmark
Estonia
Finland
France
Germany
Greece
Hungary
Iceland
Ireland
Italy
Latvia
Liechtenstein
Lithuania
Luxembourg
Malta
Netherlands
Norway
Poland
Portugal
Romania
Slovakia
Slovenia
Spain
Sweden
Switzerland
United Kingdom
```