# What certificates/medical are required to fly in Japan?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, general-aviation

I am FAA certified, but my medical certificate has lapsed. Would my pilot certificates and a fresh medical enable me to fly in Japan?

Comment: I don't know about Japan specifically, but generally speaking it's not that hard to transfer your licence between two ICAO-compliant countries, however you will need a new medical. Depending on what licence level you have there might be a theory exam and/or flight test required, but the hours you have count just about everywhere. If you get no answers here you should contact JCAB. But that's the first step, actually getting a commercial job is apparently hard for foreigners to Japan. You'll need fluent Japanese and permanent residency (so I hear).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ben. Actually, I just want to get current again. There's a flying school near here that has 172's and I'd like to rent and go fly again.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but if you're anywhere near [these guys](http://www.yokotasupport.com/aero-club/) then you could renew your medical and rent an N-reg aircraft from them. As a US pilot in a US aircraft, you shouldn't need any Japanese certification. At least, that's the way it usually works but they would be able to tell you if there are other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

With a US license, you are allowed to fly US registered (n-registered) airplanes everywhere in the world. 
Find a US CFI (in Japan) that can get you current and start flying.

The bigger problem might be, to find a Medical Examiner in Japan that is allowed to do medicals in Japan. My first search, at the FAA website (https://designee.faa.gov/SelectTypeOfSearch/SelectTypeOfSearch), didn't show anything.

Not sure if BasicMed works for you though.

Comment: This isn't universally correct. For example, in Europe, if you're a *resident* then you also need an EASA license to fly an N-registered aircraft.

Comment: @Pondlife That is not at all accurate. EASA does not have any authority to regulate issues related to a US pilot with a US license flying an N-registered aircraft. Residency has no impact on this. EASA cannot, for example, ramp-check an N-reg aircraft. That is why so many European pilots get US tickets and register their aircraft in the N-registry through holding companies.

Comment: @JuanJimenez See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/14004/62) and there's a lot of discussion on the web about it. But you may be right, it looks like the regulation has been delayed a few times, at least for private aviation.